# Custom Power Shell for SharePoint2010 Development?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

Obviously not asking for code but for functionality. What kind of PS scripts have you written and how have they made your life as a SharePoint2010 developer easier?

Answer (score 0):

Deploy Scripts, Retracted solutions if there, waited for it to actually retract. Then deployed new solution.

Wakeup Scripts which run via schedualed tasks, to wake up application pools

Upload Users profile images

Build scripts, build 1000 of sites from List